# Determine/Configure which IP address gets offered next by a DHCP server?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, tcpdump, dhcp-server

I need a way to determine the next IP address a DHCP server will offer.

RFC 2131 states:

> Each server may respond with a DHCPOFFER message that includes an available network address in the 'yiaddr' field [...].

I found no specification that this must be the next available IP address in the address pool.
Do DHCP server implementations state which IP they will offer next?
Or is there a way to tell a DHCP Server (for example isc-dhcp-server) which IP to offer next?

I need this information in order to configure tcpdump to capture traffic from/to this specific IP before the device connects to the network.

Comment: This reads like an [XY question](https://xyproblem.info/).  Instead, you could setup the DHCP server to always provide the same IP address to that device (identified by its MAC address).  Look up "DHCP IP reservation".

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't know the MAC address before the device starts to communicate, therefore I can't do DHCP IP reservation in advance.

Comment: Temporarily set the DHCP server to a very limited range of IP:s to provide? e.g. a single IP? Possible?

Comment: @Hannu this would be an idea, but it seems to be more of a workaround... Would this affect existing DHCP leases?

Comment: Now, this is just an idea, never tried. That might depend on the DHCP server software, i would expect a "well behaved" one to NOT do anything with existing leases; this should IMO only be affecting NEW requests.

Comment: @Hannu thanks! I'll look into that.